# Bug in boost::filesystem?

Tags: c++, qt, boost

This code correctly gets contents of a directory specified in selected_paths but only if the directory is "C:". If the directory is "D:" this code iterates over a root directory (the directory where the source files are located - "D:\excercizes\QT_projects\my_app") of my app. What's going on?

```
   QStringList my_app::extract_files_from_paths_(const QStringList& selected_paths)const
{
    boost::filesystem3::path path;
    QStringList result;
    for (auto e : selected_paths)
    {
       boost::filesystem3::path path(e.toStdString().c_str());
       if (boost::filesystem3::is_regular_file(path))
       {
           result.append(e);
       }
       else if (boost::filesystem3::is_directory(path) && !boost::filesystem3::is_empty(path))
       {
        std::vector<boost::filesystem3::path> paths_;
        /*add everything from this path*/
           std::copy(boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator(path), boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator(), // directory_iterator::value_type
                     std::back_inserter(paths_));
           QStringList list_of_files;
           for(auto e : paths_)
           {
               list_of_files.append(QString(e.string().c_str()));
           }
               return extract_files_from_paths_(list_of_files);

       }

    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Do not assume a bug until you have verified you are doing things correctly.

Comment: @Mat and ybungalobill thanks guys. +1 for each of you and accept Mat's; Thanks

Comment: They won't see your _thanks_. You have to post a comment below their answers, not here.

Comment: @phresnel cannot they see whole thread as I see it? and as you see it?

Comment: Of course they can, if they open this again. But they will only be notified if you comment below their answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`D:` and `D:\` are two different things on Windows.

- `D:\` designates the root of the `D` drive
- `D:` designates the *current directory* on the `D` drive

One current directory is stored per drive (per process). So it's not a `boost` bug, its a Windows feature.

In a `cmd` shell, you can see the current directory for a drive with (e.g.):

```
cd d:
```

You can change it by specifying a path:

```
cd d:\home
```

(note that this will not change your current working directory if you're not on `D`.)

`cd /d d:` and `cd /d d:\` will respectively change the shell's working directory to the current directory of `D`, and to the root of `D`.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a bug. `C:` resolves to the current directory on drive `C`, which happens to be `C:\`. `D:` resolves to the current directory on drive `D`, which happens to be `D:\excercizes\QT_projects\my_app`. You shall write `D:\` to list the files in the root of drive `D`.